# How to create a RecyclerView with two layouts? For an app chat? Or Edit the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter class?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have been looking for tutorials for some time but I can not find any that works, to inflate two layouts one that a chat bubble on the "SENDER" side and another one that "RECEIVES"

I try the code below, but it gives me a nullPointerException.

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<Chat> mDataSet;
private String mId;

private static final int CHAT_RIGHT = 1;
private static final int CHAT_LEFT = 2;

/**
 * Inner Class for a recycler view
 */
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
    }
}

/**
 * Called when a view has been clicked.
 *
 * @param dataSet Message list
 * @param id      Device id
 */
public ChatAdapter(List<Chat> dataSet, String id) {
    mDataSet = dataSet;
    mId = id;
}

@Override
public ChatAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;

    if (viewType == CHAT_RIGHT) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_chat_right, parent, false);
    } else {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_chat_left, parent, false);
    }

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (mDataSet.get(position).getId().equals(mId))
        return CHAT_RIGHT;

    return CHAT_LEFT;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Chat chat = mDataSet.get(position);
    holder.mTextView.setText(chat.getMessage());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSet.size();
}
}
```

I also tried this to inflate the RecyclerView, but it also doesn't work:

```
  mFirebaseRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                try{

                    Chat model = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

                    mChats.add(model);
                    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mChats.size() - 1);
                    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mChats.size() - 1);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Code below also doesn't work:

```
 if(key.equals(id)){
  FirebaseRecyclerAdaper.inflate(LISTRIGHT)
 }else{
  FirebaseRecyclerAdaper.inflate(LISTRIGHT)
  bla bla bla....
 }
```

It just inflates the same list. I do not know what to do.